# FindInstance and cosine system of equations

Tags: equation-solving, findinstance

I'm intrigued by `Mathematica` indisposition to find an example of the following system of equations

$$
\cos(x) + \cos(y) + \cos(z)  = \lambda_1, 
$$
$$
\cos(x+u) + \cos(y+v) + \cos(z+w)  = \lambda_2, 
$$
$$
\cos(u) + \cos(v) + \cos(w) = \lambda_3,
$$

for a given set of $\vec{\lambda}$.

For example, if I start with a given set of $x$, $y$, $z$, $u$, $v$, and $w$,

```
cond = Thread[{x, y, z, u, v, w} -> (# &@RandomReal[{-π, π}, 6])]
```

then

```
result = {Cos[x] + Cos[y] + Cos[z], Cos[x + u] + Cos[y + v] + Cos[w + z],
Cos[u] + Cos[v] + Cos[w]} /. cond
```

the following code never terminates,

```
FindInstance[Thread[{Cos[x] + Cos[y] + Cos[z],
Cos[x + u] + Cos[y + v] + Cos[w + z],
Cos[u] + Cos[v] + Cos[w]} == result], {x, y, z, u, v, w}]
```

Is there any way to obtain an instance of such system? I've tried using `Interval` and `Reals` to constrain my variables without success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to get answers for such a system is to rewrite it as a minimization problem. Define your equations (using your test case "result"):

```
eqn = Thread[{Cos[x] + Cos[y] + Cos[z], 
         Cos[x + u] + Cos[y + v] + Cos[w + z], Cos[u] + Cos[v] + Cos[w]} - result]
```

Then minimize:

```
NMinimize[Norm[eqn], {u, v, w, x, y, z}]
```

This gives you a set of values {u, v, w, x, y, z} which solve the equations. I might guess that FindInstance has problems because you are using floating point numbers and so attaining actual equality is unlikely. NMinimize returns an answer that is accurate to 10^-10 or so, which is about what you might expect from floating point calculations.